# How to iterate over objects nested in array and return just value from property

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I want to iterate over an array that has three objects nested within, within the objects i would just like to return the value of each object not the key, So far:

```
let foo = [{name: "nick"}, {name: "poop"}, {name: "bar"}]

var vals = Object.keys(foo).map(function (key) {
    console.log(foo[key]);
});
```

i am doing a problem from codewars and so far im only able to print each object. i forgot to fav the challenge so sorry i cant link the question. thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why you would call `Object.keys()` on an array. It sounds like you want a simple `for (let obj of foo) console.log(obj.name)`?

Comment: nice works great thanks